# Gaining access to data acquired by AppleScript outside of the script

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I'd be interested in using the data that I acquire with an AppleScript in another Framework, or even to write it to disk (the former is preferable).  For example, I have an AppleScript where I ask QuickTime Player to open a file and play it, then I poll the file's playhead location in a loop.

Is there any way that I can ship/pipe that data off elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being clear as to what you are trying to do, maybe what you are looking for is a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

You create one like this...

`mkfifo mypipe`

and you could listen or consume what comes down the pipe like this...

`tail -f mypipe`

you can now send data down the pipe from applescript like this...

```
on timeStamp()
    return (current date) as string
end timeStamp

set aname to "/home/user/some/dir/mypipe"

repeat 10 times
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of timeStamp() & " > " & aname
    delay 5
end repeat
```

Comment: this worked the first time i tried it and then it seems that the OS doesn't find the pipe.  I attempted to `rm` it to no avail.  i suppose it would be nice to pick up on the pipe with a python script with os.mkfifo(), but not sure how to do that.  it's probably out of the question's scope.

Comment: I think I might be having an issue with the file being blocked between programs accessing it.  I was able to `rm` the file from within my script, but occasionally the applescript will freeze due to the file being reserved by another program.

Comment: @jml Can't say why you are having problems. Sounds very strange. I've run the script above on Snow Leopard many times with no problems. Possibly an antivirus or security product getting in the way?

Comment: I think it has to do with the pipe being run from another parent process or something like this.  If you have any thoughts on how to trouble-shoot that particular, I would be greatly appreciative.  Basically, I need to know whether or not it is OK to create a pipe w/ one program and access the pipe's input from another program.  I thought this is precisely what `tail` is doing - just a file read at the end of the day.

Comment: @jml Saw your other question, will answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a gander at [this page](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-09.html). It has a few examples on how to write variables to a file.

Comment: cool.  any hope in using the data in real time?  Also, I'd assume that if this is the only way to get the data that I'd have to use a similar file read op to push data into the applescript context?